# Asynchronous function and AJAX request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

If I call an asynchronous function inside a listener for the second time (without "let"), I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: updatePromoList is not a function

If I had 'let' to 'updatePromoList' variable, this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'updatePromoList' before initialization

I use SmartAdmin template.

The goal is to receive true or false from the function only after the AJAX request has finished.

My code:

```
async function updatePromoList() {
    var request_status = false;

    await $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https...',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            request_status = true;
        },
    });

    return request_status;
}

$('#.select2').on('select2:select select2:unselect', async function(e) {
    // let (yes or not...)
    let updatePromoList = await updatePromoList();
    if (!updatePromoList) {
        // code
    }
});
```

Solution:

```
let updatePromoListCheck;
updatePromoListCheck = await updatePromoList();
if (updatePromoListCheck) {...}
```

Comment: Your code overwrites the value of the global `updatePromoList`.

Comment: Re edit: Now you are trying to call `updatePromoList` which is a local variable to which you haven't yet assigned a value.

Comment: Don't shadow variables. Do use [linting tools to warn you when you do](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow).

Comment: Very simply: don't use the same name for variables and functions.

Comment: `let updatePromoList = await updatePromoList(); if (!updatePromoList)` change to  `let updatePromoListResult = await updatePromoList(); if (!updatePromoListResult)`